# Magic Properties from PHP in Java

Tags: java, php, syntax

in PHP I have a Model class, that loads data from the database. Since many other classes use this Model, it's easy for me to load variables like this.

```
public function loadModel( $id ) {
    $result = $this->queryData( self::RETURN_MODE_ASSOC, array(), array('id' => $id ));
    if (count($result) > 0 ) {
        $this->loadRow( $result[0] );
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

public function loadRow( $row ) {
        foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
```

Now, for each Class that uses the model. I can simply access these variables. How is that possible in Java? I have a class

User and a Model named Model.

I mean, I can't simply use `this.key` like this

```
JSONObject jsonObj  = new JSONObject(result);
Iterator iter       = jsonObj.keys();

while(iter.hasNext()){

    this.key = (String)iter.next();
}
```

Is it possible in Java to do this/

Comment: You need reflection.  However, you should use an existing ORM, such as Hibernate, instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Hi. I already read a bit about reflections, but everything I saw about reflection was, that you at least need to know the class name. Do you have any tutorial on how I could use Reflection for that purpose? Or should I reformat my question because it's too general?